# In kubernetes, how do I select by label is X or not set?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I would like to be able to use `kubectl apply` and have it select all of the kubernetes objects that either have the label or don't have the label set at all.

I can do this with

```
kubectl apply -Rf config/ -l label1=val1
```

and

```
kubectl apply -Rf config/ -l '!label1'
```

But if I have multiple labels, this quickly gets out of hand:

```
kubectl apply -Rf config/ -l '!label1,!label2'

kubectl apply -Rf config/ -l 'label1=val1,!label2'

kubectl apply -Rf config/ -l '!label1,label2=val2'

kubectl apply -Rf config/ -l 'label1=val1,label2=val2'
```

What I'd like to do is something like

```
kubectl apply -Rf config/ -l 'label1 in (val1, <null>),label2 in (val2, <null>)'
```

Is that possible?

Comment: are you open to constructing the permutations programmatically, then feeding that list of pods to `xargs kubectl apply` or you need it to be in one shot?

Comment: separately, don't forget that `kubectl` is merely a friendly way of invoking the k8s api; you may experience more success by actually writing a program that does what you describe (so: more programming and less shell, if that makes sense)

Comment: another option: `kubectl get -o json pods | jq -r '.items[] as $p|select(.....)|$p.metadata.name' | xargs kubectl apply ...` to select the pods based on whatever combinations of criteria you could imagine